# Exam sample: why is this variable in C++ producing such an output?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Working out the below code by hand:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func (int a, int b) {
    static int c = 1;
    return a + b * (c *= -1);
}

int main () {
    int a = 2, b = 3;
    int c = func(a, b);

    a *= a++;
    b *= ++b;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, func(a, b));
}
```

I calculate the variables in `printf()` to be as follows:

```
a = 5, b = 16, c = -1, func(a, b) = -11
```

however my compiler tells me the last value is in fact 21.

Output:

```
a = 5, b = 16, c = -1, func(a, b) = 21n
```

I'd calculate my value as `(16*-1) + 5`

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: An exam, it's a test. Bettering knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a *= a++;
b *= ++b;
```

both statements are undefined behavior in C. They are violating C sequence points rules.

```
a *= a++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = a * a++;
```

and modifying an object twice between the previous and the next sequence point is undefined behavior in C (C99, 6.5p2).

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime neither

Comment: So please explain to me what's happening and why my first 3 answers are correct?

Comment: How does b get to 16 is what I'm asking?

Comment: `How does b get to 16` as it is undefined behavior, the compiler is free to set this value to 16, 42 or whatever.

Comment: That's ridiculous, how could this be an exam question then with no clear answer? please clarify.

Comment: Not to say I don't believe you, am just curious as to why such a thing could happen?

Comment: The answer is: this program is erroneous. Don't expect any reliable output from it. It is the same way this is erroneous: `printf("%d\n", 1 / 0);` is.

Comment: Yes, but there is a documented answer to this question and it is from a reputable exam board. How, if the compiler has done what it likes with b, have I calculated the same answer for B?

Comment: Well, it seems that the exam board in question is only "reputable"...

Comment: @IvanVergiliev That's a bit like saying, "this person is only 'trusted'"

Comment: Anyway thanks @ouah for you help, I will explore some more :)

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime trust me this program is wrong, and the only correct answer is: the behavior is undefined.